# add-back-button-to-survey-list-in-sharepoint-online - Changes in NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have looked into this [article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180160/add-back-button-to-survey-list-in-sharepoint-2013) which looks like a solution. I followed the steps, opened NewForm.asp with SharePoint designer and found the script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrameScript">
    if (document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame") != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame").className="ms-areaseparator";
    }


</script>

**I then copied the code from the example in the /script box. I am a complete newby so chances are here is where the mistakes occur. The following code is now in my NewForm.aspx but after saving, nothing changes in SharePoint online?**

<script type="text/javascript" id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrameScript">
    if (document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame") != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame").className="ms-areaseparator";
    }

    $(document).ready(function () { 
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', execOperation); 
});
function execOperation() {
try {
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
}
catch (err) {
alert('Unable to get Context' + err);
}
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(appplyLogic, 'sp.js');
function appplyLogic()
{
var nextButton = $('input[value=\'Next\']'); 
nextButton.bind("click", function(){
var cLoc = window.location.href;
if(cLoc.toLowerCase().indexOf('newform.aspx') > -1)
{
localStorage.next = '';
localStorage.next = cLoc + "$";
}
else
{
localStorage.next += cLoc + "$"; 
}
});
}

</script>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We only need to edit EditFrom.aspx.

Edit EditFrom.aspx in Advanced Mode using SharePoint Designer.

Add the following code under `<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` tag:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () { 
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', applyLogic); 
});

//ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(applyLogic, 'sp.js'); 
function applyLogic()
{

  var isBack = localStorage.getItem('isBack');
  if (isBack == 'true') {
    localStorage.setItem('isBack', 'false');
    goBack();
  }

  var nextButton = $('input[value="Next"]');
  if(nextButton.length == 0) 
  {
    nextButton = $('input[value="Finish"]'); 
  }
  var firstField = getParameterByName("FirstField");
  if (firstField != "")
  {
    nextButton.parent('td').before('<input id="btnBack" type="button" value="Back" />');
    var backButton = $('input#btnBack');
    backButton.attr('class', 'ms-ButtonHeightWidth');
    backButton.click(function () { 
      if ($('input[value="Finish"]').length == 0) // only trigger next if next != finish...
      {
        localStorage.setItem('isBack', 'true');
        nextButton.trigger('click'); 
      }
      else {
        goBack();
      }
    });
  }

  nextButton.bind("click", function(){
    var isBack = localStorage.getItem('isBack');
    if (isBack != 'true')
    {
      var cLoc = window.location.href; 
      var firstField = getParameterByName("FirstField");

      if (!localStorage.next || firstField == '') // is first page or localstorage.next undefined
        localStorage.next = '';

      localStorage.next += cLoc + "$"; 
    }
  });
}


function goBack()
{
  var cLoc = window.location.href; 
  var str = localStorage.next; 
  if (!str)
    str = '';

  if (str.charAt(str.length - 1) == '$') {
    str = str.substr(0, str.length - 1); 
  }
  var n = str.lastIndexOf('$'); 
  var result = str.substring(n + 1); 
  var withoutLastDollar = str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf("$"));
  if (n>-1)
    localStorage.next = withoutLastDollar + "$";
  if (result + '' == '' || (result+'').toLowerCase().indexOf('newform.aspx')>-1) {
    localStorage.next = '';
    location.href = "EditForm.aspx?ID=" + getParameterByName("ID");
  }
  else
    window.location = result; 
}


function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

</script>
```

[image]

Save the page.

Result:

[image]

It will back to the previous question when click "Back" button.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for giving me input. Much appreciated. I have copied the code to the place pointed out. (I have a screenshot but not sure how to add this). Unlucky for me the survey still does not have a back button :-(. 

What could i do wrong? I saved the code. Refreshed. 

Thanks again!!!

Comment: You can insert the screenshot to your post as the comment does not allow use add  images. Please provide your steps for checking. Did you add the code after <asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"> in EditForm.aspx

Comment: Thanks again. I added some screenshots. Could it have anything to do with somekind of site setting within SharePoint online? I have admin rights so if necessary i can change any option. But i sill hope i am doing something wrong.

Comment: please edit your own post and add screenshots instead of editing my answer.

Comment: Did you edit the EditForm.aspx in advanced mode? Use F12 to debug your page.

Comment: Sorry for editing your post. I tried to debug by pressing F12. The survey starts but after that i am not sure what to do.

Comment: Hi. Yes i did edit the file in Advanced mode. I am stuck now. Can't find the reason why it is not behaving as it supposed to do.

Comment: So I've implemented this code and the button appears just fine. However it does not actually go back to the previous page, it goes to the next one (acting like I hit the "Next" button). Furthermore the button will disappear once the page finished loading. The code is throwing no errors (checked with debug). So I'm not sure if I messed up copying your code somewhere or if it needs to be changed. Any suggestions? Also I don't have the ability to comment and need help. Please do not delete this entry.